# VBA Track file usage

Tags: vba, email, sharepoint

I currently have an excel file that produces client statements. I need to track who has run their statements.
Currently, whenever statements are produced I have a macro that send me an email with their user name.  However people running on a Thin Client system they get a prompt;

'A program is trying to send an email message on your behalf...'

IS there some way I can get rid of this prompt and still send the email, or has anyone got any other ideas on how to track usage.  I share the file through Share Point.  So that might have some capabilities?

Thank you

Comment: Just use a hidden sheet and write the data to it. That prompt is a security feature of Outlook and is there for a good reason - I'd leave that as it is. Set the sheets visibility to `xlSheetVeryHidden` and put a password on the VBProject.

Comment: I don't think that will work as some people take the file from sharepoint and save it to their own desktop.  Therefore I won't be able to see the usage.

Comment: You can set up notifications in share point whenever a file is amended, but I'm not sure that would work if they do a Save As... Other than that you're options are a bit thin. You could set up a shared workbook on the sharepoint and tell the macro to write to that instead perhaps

Answer (score 2):

If there is a location on your network that everyone has access to you can write a log file.  Most likely a spot on the Sharepoint server.

Something like this called from the code that is currently sending out the email.

In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and select references.  Select "Microsoft scripting runtime"

```
Private Sub LogUsage()

    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim fs As FileSystemObject
    Dim strLogFile As String

    strLogFile = "\\servername\sharename\log\Usage.txt"

    'Check if the file exists, if it does, open it, if it doesn't create it
    Set fs = New FileSystemObject
    If fs.FileExists(strLogFile) = True Then
        Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(strLogFile, ForAppending)
    Else
        Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile(strLogFile, True, False)
    End If

    'Log your entry
    ts.WriteLine "Used by " & Environ$("Username") & " at " & Now & " on computer " & Environ$("Computername")

     'Clean up
     ts.Close: Set ts = Nothing
     Set fs = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a shared database, like SQL server or Access on a network share, rather than an e-mail.  It's easier to work with than separate e-mails.

If you must use e-mail, you can use a CDO object in your Excel macro, but your users must have access to an SMTP server on your network (usually an Exchange server works for this; look at your Outlook settings and see what server it's connected to).  Generally this is not a problem if everyone has access to the same LAN resources.

Add a reference in the VBA editor to Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library (Tools->References in VBA.  Don't worry about the "Windows 2000"; it should be available on your system).

Example code

```
Dim iMsg As CDO.Message
Dim iConf As CDO.Configuration
Dim Flds As ADODB.Fields

Set iMsg = New CDO.Message
Set iConf = New CDO.Configuration

Set Flds = iConf.Fields

With Flds
    .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    'Put the address of your SMTP server here
    .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.example.com"
    .Item(cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = 10
    .Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
    .Item(cdoSendUserName) = "Username To Authenticate SMTP Server With"
    .Item(cdoSendPassword) = "Password To Authenticate SMTP Server With"
    .Item(cdoURLGetLatestVersion) = True
    .Update
End With

With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .From = "from@example.com"
    .ReplyTo = "replyto@example.com"
    .MimeFormatted = False
    .AutoGenerateTextBody = False
    .To = "to@example.com"
    .CC = "cc@example.com"
    .BCC = "bcc@example.com"
    .Subject = "Subject of Email"
    .HTMLBody = "<body>HTML text to send</body>"

    'If you need to add attachments
    .AddAttachment "C:\Local\Path\To\Attachment.xlsx"

    .Send
End With
```