# Find out what workbook called a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in workbook ABC.  I want to find out what other workbooks are calling this macro, since we are going to be replacing its functionality.  Is there a way to tell what workbook is calling the macro when it executes?  Or does Application.Run hide that from the called macro?

Comment: [Application.Caller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193687(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Not really - beyond inspecting the Call stack manually. `Application.Caller` won't work whether the macro is called using Run or directly by another routine - only if it's invoked as an `OnAction` property.

Comment: Could you change the macro to add in a new inputbox, requiring the user to manually type the workbook being used, and timestamp a field somewhere with that users ID, the time, and their manual input?

Comment: No the problem is I don't know what calls it, and I don't want to break the worksheets that do.  Basically there is a scheduling system we use that is built in excel.  We're replacing it with an APS, but we will still be using some of the spreadsheets for planning purposes.  I want to know what sheets are driven by this excel schedule instead of being driven purely by our ERP database (which has a copy of the schedule written into it).

Comment: Could you add some logging to the macro like in my answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888528/vba-track-file-usage/32890119#32890119

Comment: @MatthewD That looks promising, and should give us enough info (with our setup, we can actually just get away with making the macro do nothing, but I'd rather not do that).  I was hoping there was a way to see the actual workbook, but this looks like the best vba has to offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to get the workbook name.  You could log the workstation and user, then go to the workstation and start Excel and go to File -> Recent to see the recent workbooks used on the computer.

You can write a log file to the location where the workbook is that contains the macro.

Something like this called from the macro.

> In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and select references. Select "Microsoft scripting runtime"

```
Private Sub LogUsage()

    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim fs As FileSystemObject
    Dim strLogFile As String

    strLogFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Usage.txt"

    'Check if the file exists, if it does, open it, if it doesn't create it
    Set fs = New FileSystemObject
    If fs.FileExists(strLogFile) = True Then
        Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(strLogFile, ForAppending)
    Else
        Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile(strLogFile, True, False)
    End If

    'Log your entry
    ts.WriteLine "Used by " & Environ$("Username") & " at " & Now & " on computer " & Environ$("Computername")

     'Clean up
     ts.Close: Set ts = Nothing
     Set fs = Nothing

 End Sub
```