# Great Plains Smarlist runs excel macro twice

Tags: excel, vba, dynamics-gp

I wrote a smartlist and an excel macro enabled workbook that is supposed to sum two columns and put the total under each column on a new row.  It works perfectly straight from excel but when run from GP Smartlist export it sums my columns twice.  The first time it sums them correctly then it takes the total and adds it to the sum giving me twice the original sum on a completely different row.

[image: Two sum cells]

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub sumColumns()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sum1 As Double
    Dim sum2 As Double
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer: counter = 0
    'ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Value2 = "" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Value2 = GetLastRowOnSheet(ThisWorkbook)
        lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Value2
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If


    For i = 2 To lastRow
         sum1 = sum1 + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 11).Value2
         sum2 = sum2 + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 12).Value2
    Next i


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(lastRow + 2, 11).Value2 = sum1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(lastRow + 2, 12).Value2 = sum2

    End Sub

    Function GetLastRowOnSheet(ByVal book As Workbook) As Long
        Dim lastRow As Long
        With ActiveSheet
            GetLastRowOnSheet = Sheets(1).Cells(1048576, 11).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
    End Function
```

I am relatively certain that GP is running the macro twice but if anyone can help me figure this out that would be great.

Comment: How are you triggering the macro?

Comment: @A.S.H I'm new to great plains so bear with me.  I am doing an excel export of the smartlist and one of the options is to pickup the macro enabled sheet as a template that I setup.  When setup in GP you tell it the xlsm file and the function to run.

Comment: You could try creating a log file and writing an entry to it each time it runs so you can see if it is indeed running it twice. Rule that out

Comment: Is that an easy get within GP or do you mean setup VBA to write to a log?

Comment: I mean setup vba to log it. See my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103416/find-out-what-workbook-called-a-macro/33104772#33104772  Then just call LogUsage() in your sub.

Comment: I'll look into that.  If it turns out it is running it twice are there any suggestions?  Does it look like my vba code is causing this?

Comment: Nothing obvious to me.