# VBA MACRO Write in the next line of Notepad

Tags: vba

I'm having problems on how to write in the notepad using vba macro.
I want to track who is opening my file including the date when the file was open.

For example, I opened my report. My username should be listed in the text file. And when USER_X open this file. His name should be listed below my name. And when USER_Y open this file, his name should be listed below USER_X.
Note: Name's should not be overwritten.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Do you have any sample code of what you have already tried?

Comment: See MatthewD's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888528/vba-track-file-usage/32890119#32890119   You can call something like this from the Workbook_Open event.

Comment: MatthewD's codes worked for me! This is what I need. Thanks for your help Tim! :)

Answer (score 0):

code somthing like below

```
Sub WirteText()

Dim strFile_Path As String
strFile_Path = "C:\output.txt" 'Change as per your test folder and exiting file path to append it.
Open strFile_Path For Append As #1
Write #1, "This is my sample text"
Close #1
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi singhm0077, but this is the one worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888528/vba-track-file-usage/32890119#32890119. Thanks anyway! :)